# Error on trying to run a simple RPC program

Tags: c, ubuntu, rpc

I am trying to run a simple RPC program which I have created using rpcgen. 
Its a simple factorial program. This is my first RPC program. 
The make works fine.Executables are also created. 
But when trying to run the executables, I get this error:

```
$sudo ./fact_server 
Cannot register service: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
unable to register (FACTPROGRAM, FACTVERSION, udp).
```

I tried running the same program on another pc with the same OS (ubuntu). It runs perfect there.

Comment: Sounds like something else is already running on the port you want to bind to

Comment: Try running `/etc/init.d/rpcbind start`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First you check that portmapper is working or not, use `rpcinfo` to check it.
If you get any error then install `portmap`

Answer (score 7):

Check whether the service is running using `rpcinfo`. Here's what I get.

```
$ rpcinfo 
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
        24    5    udp       0.0.0.0.3.99           -          superuser
        24    5    tcp       0.0.0.0.3.100          -          superuser
```

If the service is not running, you have to start it with `rpcbind`. On Ubuntu I needed root privileges to run the service.

Answer (score 5):

There is a *bug/feature* in recent Linux releases of rpcbind - it is now not active/running after system boot, but should somehow be "socket activated" according to  systemctl configuration rpcbind.service file in /usr/lib/systemd/system/:

```
[Install] 
Also=rpcbind.socket
```

Check this thread on same bug/feature caused Ubuntu issues (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rpcbind/+bug/1558196).

**The short answer to yours (ours) issue with rpcbind is** - in order to run the RPC server code, **do this amendment to systemctrl configuration** of your system:

```
sudo systemctl add-wants multi-user.target rpcbind
```

Now, the intended way to set rpcbind running is to somehow access /var/run/rpcbind.sock, I would owe much to some Unix/Linux guru that may enlighten me on what RPC server application code shall do in order to achieve this rpcbind "socket activation" effect.

Comment: I had this issue after restart and your last line helped - thanks

Comment: @serup: You mean 'sudo systemctl .... ' line? Since my very last paragraph is a question, I don't know the answer to still. How to achieve that 'socket activation' - since trying to use rpc service does not do it.

Comment: yes after running last line and restart of system, then issues where gone

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises due to unavailability of utility like `portmap` or `rpcbind`. Install either of them to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**How to install rpcgen**

Type this command on the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install rpcbind
```

but at sometimes the above code won't help you to install `rpcgen`.

[image]

At that time you have to follow these steps.Then you can easily install it.
you should follow this step by step

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install rpcbind
```

Finally you can check it by using this command `rpcinfo`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just install the following and try.

```
sudo apt install libc-dev-bin
```

For more information check the following GitHub.
https://github.com/riyazathali/RPC-HelloWorld

Comment: Welcome ot stackoverflow! Are you sure this will help? It seems the person already marked another answer as accepted about 8 years ago.

Comment: Yeah. sure. Because, this way will deviate without relying on rpcbind. You can easily try out this by stopping the rcpbind or uninstalling the rcpbind

Comment: Okay, I have no experience at all, just wanted to to have a bit more information on your answer :) Thanks!

Comment: Check this GitHub
https://github.com/riyazathali/RPC-HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

I had error using `rpcinfo` as well. Finally I had to run:

```
/etc/init.d/rpcbind start
```

as suggested in [here](https://www.looklinux.com/error-cannot-register-service-rpc-unable-to-receive-errno-connection-refused/).

After getting:

```
[info] Already running: rcpbind.
```

rpc server binary was able to register.

Answer (score 0):

undefined reference to `xdr_wrapstring'

I think their is an issue on RCPBIND in latest ubuntu version? 22.04

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33617519)